# How does the strong law of large numbers hold for Bernoulli Random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

The strong law of large numbers states that for iid random variables $X_1, \ldots X_n,\ldots$, we have $$\mathbb P\left(\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{X_1 + \ldots + X_n}{n} = \mu\right) = \mathbb P\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}Y_n = \mu\right) = 1$$
where $\mu=\mathbb E[X_i]\; \forall i$. So I considered Bernoulli random variables to see this, where $X_i \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p), p=0.5$. The sum of any $n$ Bernoulli random variables is a Binomial random variable $Y_n \sim \text{Binomial}(n,p), p=0.5$. In our case, $\mu = p = 0.5$. So as we increase $n$, we should see that $\mathbb P(Y_n = 0.5) \to 1$. I used Julia to plot the pdfs of $Y_n$ for several different $n$, by scaling the x-axis to be between 0 and 1 (since $Y_n$ is between 0 and 1). Here is the plot.

[image: PDFs of Binomial Random Variables]

Contrary to expectations, as $n$ increases, $\mathbb P(Y_n = \mu)$ is decreasing! I'm sure I'm making some kind of conceptual mistake, but I don't see where I'm going wrong! **Why is the probability of** $Y_n = \mu$ **going down as** $n$ **increases?**

---

For reference, the code I used:

```
using Plots, Distributions
plot(title="PDFs of Binomial Random Variables")
for n in collect(10 .^ (1:5))
    plot!(LinRange(0,1,n+1), pdf(Binomial(n,0.5)), label="n=$n")
    # plot!(LinRange(0,1,n+1), cdf(Binomial(n,0.5), 0:n), label="n=$n")
end
plot!(dpi=300)
savefig("plot.png")
```

Comment: You're confusing $\mathbb P(\lim Y_n=\mu)=1$ with $\lim\mathbb P(Y_n=\mu)=1$. The former is true but the latter is false.

Comment: Don't you have to normalize the data first, i.e. calculate z-scores? That is, it is the z-scores that approach a normal curve as $n$ increases. Also the limiting distribution, i.e. the normal curve, is for a continuous variable, so probability of a specific real number loses meaning.

Comment: @AndreasBlass How do I find the limiting random variable then? It is still the limit of the sequence of Binomial random variables right? How can I use this to see that the limiting random variable is $\mu$ with probability 1?

Comment: @coffeemath Doesn't the strong law of large numbers actually say something about the probability of a specific real number ($\mu$) being equal to 1?

Comment: The random variable $Y_n$ is the constant function $\mu$ (ignoring sets of measure zero).

Comment: That letter  $\mu$ is often use for the expected value of (any) random variable. For the standard normal this $\mu$ is $0,$ not $1.$ But in no way is the probability $1$ that the variable is exactly equal to $\mu.$

Comment: @AndreasBlass I know that $Y_{\infty}$, the limit of a sequence of random variables $Y_n$ as $n\to \infty$, is the constant random variable according to the strong law. But how can I see that as the limit of a sequence of Binomial random variables? I'm just trying to verify strong law for myself using this example. If the pmf (probability mass function) of the sequence of random variables is not converging to that of the limiting random variable, how is the sequence $Y_n$ converging to that random variable $Y_\infty$?

Comment: Pointwise limit of PMF don't tell much about the convergence in distribution, much less about the almost-sure convergence. You would want to study the limit of CDFs instead.

Comment: @coffeemath I see what you mean now... You're saying that if I want to look at pdfs, I should look at the z-scores to connect it to the Central Limit Theorem... But even the strong law looks at the limiting random variable as the limit of a sequence of random variables... I wanted to intuitively understand how this limiting random variable's distribution becomes such that its probability is 1 for some real number $\mu$.

Comment: @SangchulLee I am beginning to see that.... I plotted the cdfs and they are definitely approaching what one would expect. But I am not able to intuitively understand why the pdf isn't showing similar convergence. Any idea how to see that?

Comment: The "decreasing" of PMFs $p_{Y_n}(y)$ is simply telling that each individual value of $p_{Y_n}$ is contributing less to the whole distribution. However, the non-zero values of $p_{Y_n}$ become more "concentrated" (in the sense that the range of $Y_n$ becomes more "dense"), so their collective contribution will look very different. So I suggest you to draw a probability histogram (histogram where the total area is normalized to $1$). This is essentially the same as what the user coffeemath suggested.

Comment: @FreezingFire In most cases the limiting distribution of a sequence of random variables (call them $X_n$) is a *continuous* random variable say $X.$ This happens even for many sequences of *discrete* random variables $X_n.$ In that case, there can be a positive probability that $X_n=k$ for some $k,$ but the probability that the limiting random variable X is exactly some specific real number $c$ will automatically be zero. That's the nature of a continuous random variable. What s done is to define probabilities for *intervals* of reals, by integrating the pdf of $X$ over the interval.

Comment: @coffeemath So what is $Y_{\infty} = \lim_{n\to \infty} Y_n$? As I understand it, it is a discrete random variable having a probability mass function such that $\mathbb P(Y_{\infty}=\mu)=0$... So the limiting random variable should be a discrete random variable right?

Comment: @SangchulLee I see what you mean, and in fact doing that intuitively explains the weak law of large numbers ($\lim{n\to\infty} \mathbb P(|Y_n - \mu| > \epsilon) = 0$). But strong law says something about the limit of a sequence of random variables... which itself seems to be a discrete, and more specifically, constant random variable. I'm finding it difficult to picture this from my example...

Comment: @FreezingFire Your last comment about $Y_\infty$ shows you do not understand what a continuous distribution is. $Y_\infty$ is a continuous distribution not a discrete one. For a continuous distribution the probability of any specific real number is $0.$ As I wrote, and if you have ever used a continuous distribution, it is the probability of the variable lying in an *interval* $[a,b]$ which is found by *integrating* the pdf from $a$ to $b.$

Comment: @coffeemath Firstly there was a typo in my comment, I meant $P(Y_\infty=\mu)=1$, sorry about that. Now, if the probability of a random variable $X$ taking the value $\mu$ is one, i.e. $P(X=\mu) = 1$, then $P(X=\alpha) = 0\forall\alpha\ne\mu$. Is this random variable $X$ a continuous or a discrete random variable? Other than that, I have of course used continuous distributions, however the strong law says something about convergence of a sequence of continuous random variables to a random variable which seems to be discrete.